# Forcing left join to only return one row from matching Ids in the right table

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, left-join

I have two tables in which I'd like to join, the right table sometimes has more than 1 row for each ID. But I'm not interested to have all the matches, only the first one is enough.

How can I do that?

Example:

Foo:

```
     Id             FooColumns....
     100             xxxxxxxx
     200             xxxxxxxx
     300             xxxxxxxx
     400             xxxxxxxx
```

Bar:

```
     Id             BarColumns....
     100             yyyyyyyy
     100             zzzzzzzz
     200             yyyyyyyy
     200             zzzzzzzz
```

What I want to have is :

FooBar:

```
     Id             FooColumns....     BarColumns
     100             xxxxxxxx            yyyyyyyy
     200             xxxxxxxx            yyyyyyyy
     300             xxxxxxxx              nulls
     400             xxxxxxxx              nulls
```

---

```
Query: 
   Select F.*,B.* from Foo f left join Bar b on f.Id=B.Id   ??
```

Comment: How do you define "first"? Records in a table are inherently unsorted, so you have to define order yourself.

Comment: You must have another column that can help pick out "the first one".  Maybe  EditDate or something?  SQL doesn't guarantee a given sort logic unless you tell it what it is.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I really don't care which column to pick. I just wanted to pick one. Instead of ending up with multiple rows. I reckon the outer apply does the work. don't you think?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
Select F.*, B.*
from Foo f left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.id order by id) as seqnum
      from bar b
     ) b
     on f.Id = B.Id and seqnum = 1;
```

The `order by` specifies what you mean by "first".  The `order by id` is an arbitrary ordering.

And alternative method uses `outer apply`:

```
Select F.*, B.*
from Foo f outer apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from bar b
      where f.Id = B.Id
     ) b;
```

In this case, you would add an `order by` to the subquery to get the "first" based on some column.  Also, this should have better performance than the previous version.

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried the outer apply query, it returns the same value in bar table for all IDs in foo. It doesn't join the two tables correctly

Comment: I think if I add a b.ID=f.ID clause inside the parenthesise, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer is perfect apart from that last sentence. The performance depends on the size of the tables.  I hope I get this right:
* The version with OUTER APPLY is better when there many rows per partition. That is, if each `Id` in table `Foo` has many `Id`s in table `bar`, the OUTER APPLY tends to produce a better execution plan,
* The version with row_number is better when there are few rows par partition. That is, each `Id` in table `Foo` has only a small number of `Id`s in table `bar`.

Comment: it's great but how to use the same on PHPMyAdmin because this outer apply is not acceptable in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @heySushil . . . This question is tagged SQL Server.  You can ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation -- and a tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for. That row_number over (partition by) stuff never made a lot of sense to me, but it allows you to grab a specific row number from the resulting query. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you back the same rows every run:

```
SELECT
  F.*,
  B.*
FROM Foo f
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           Id,
           MIN(BarColumn)
           FROM bar
           GROUP BY id) b
ON f.Id = b.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get desired resultset is to use `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
Select F.*,B.* 
from Foo f 
left join (SELECT DISTINCT Id
         ,FIRST_VALUE(FooColumns) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY id) AS FooColumns
           FROM bar)b on f.Id=B.Id;
```

**[RextesterDemo](http://rextester.com/NXAE42977)**

Answer (score -1):

add LIMIT 1 option to your query here's an example :

```
Select C From T LIMIT 1.
```

This will return only one row , you can also get the last Item if you change the order as descendant 
 Example :

```
SELECT C FROM T ORDER BY DESC LIMIT1
```

Comment: Question is tagged sql-server, it doesn't implement `LIMIT`.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice but he ca use `TOP` in Microsoft SQL Server to mimic the `LIMIT` clause but There are cases where it just doesn't work , Some use `ROW_NUMBER()` if your using MS sql server since 2005 version ( i think) This is the best solution (for now) that works solely as part of the query.
Another solution is to use `TOP `to fetch the first count + offset rows, and then seek past the first offset rows dependeing on the objective.

Comment: How do you use that in the left join?